# Encoding incorrect on some pages

Tags: html, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a website entirely in Italian language that has been working very well for years.
I noticed today that mid way down 1 of the pages (and I only find the error on one page), the accented latin characters are not displaying correctly.

The page in question is:
http://it.jeyjoo.com/agenzia-seo-ottimizzazione-dei-motori-di-ricerca

Again, to repeat, through the rest of the website I do not have this issue, and the other pages use the same PHP template files.

Character encoding set to UTF-8 via htaccess.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That part of the content on that particular page is not actually encoded in UTF-8 but in Latin-1.

Comment: Thanks Deceze, but as far as I can see, the page is encoded utf-8 just like the rest - line 7 of the source code.

Comment: That line tells the browser how to *interpret* the page. It doesn't actually *make* the page UTF-8 encoded!

Comment: Ok thanks, but I also have the following line in my htaccess (without the quotes): "AddType 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' php"

Comment: Ugh, *facepalm*. Please start reading these two to see the problem: http://kunststube.net/encoding, http://kunststube.net/frontback

Comment: Oh man... The data itself, wherever it is coming from, is Latin-1 encoded! I don't know where the data comes from, so I can only guess. If it's from a file you `include`, then that file was saved as Latin-1 instead of UTF-8 in your text editor, for example.

Comment: I have still not resolved this. The strange thing is, all other pages and the site are fine - and they use the same htaccess, head tags and character encoding. To get around the problem, on the page causing problems, I have encoded the latin symbols for example à as &agrave; . If anyone does know of a solution I would be interested to know. Thanks

Comment: In your text editor, go to Save As... and save the file as UTF-8. If that's what you have to do, I don't know where the content comes from.